# Проблема с использованием иконок

Tags: java, android

Я сделал NavigationDrawer с помощью MaterialDrawer от Mike Penz. 
Он отлично работает, но когда я пытаюсь заменить значки "FontAwesome" на "GoogleMaterial" или другие получаю сообщение об ошибке

> "Unfortunately, App has stopped."

Все работает только со значками "FontAwesome"

Как может быть решена эта проблема?

Заранее спасибо!

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.FontAwesome;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.DividerDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Drawer.Result drawerResult = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerResult = new Drawer()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_database).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_database),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_map).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_map_marker),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_guides).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_book),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_crafting).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_build),
                        //new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_tools).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_build),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_links).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_link),
                        new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        //new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_feedback).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_envelope)
                        //new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_changes).withIcon(Typeicons.Icon.typ_clipboard)
                )
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerResult.isDrawerOpen()) {
            drawerResult.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blackToolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
            android:transitionName="actionBar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.enotboris.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:0.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:devicon-typeface:2.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:meteocons-typeface:1.1.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.7.22.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:weather-icons-typeface:2.0.10.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:typeicons-typeface:2.0.7.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:entypo-typeface:1.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:devicon-typeface:2.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:foundation-icons-typeface:3.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:ionicons-typeface:2.0.1.2@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.enotboris.dayz">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
01-25 15:29:09.899 2594-2594/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: The font for the given icon isn't registered!
                                                     at com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable.icon(IconicsDrawable.java:121)
                                                     at com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable.<init>(IconicsDrawable.java:89)
                                                     at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem.convertView(PrimaryDrawerItem.java:190)
                                                     at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.adapter.DrawerAdapter.getView(DrawerAdapter.java:125)
                                                     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1612)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2106)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1217)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Пример:

[Использовал иконки "FontAwesome"](http://s41.radikal.ru/i093/1701/49/0dcf7789d128.png)

[Использовал "GoogleMaterialDesign" и другие иконки](http://i056.radikal.ru/1701/38/8ce8313497b4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить вашу проблему можно так

```
Iconics.registerFont(new GoogleMaterial());
```

Связано это с тем, что данная библиотека включает в себя Android-Iconics. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics/issues/67)

Comment: куда это добавить надо? я просто новичок в java

Comment: Можете прям в вашем наследнике Application добавить

Comment: вот так должно быть?

Comment: [ТЫК](http://s019.radikal.ru/i634/1701/11/ba02d935fad7.png)              Тогда "init" подчеркивает и пишет "Error:(21, 16) error: cannot find symbol method init(Context)"

Comment: Обновили библиотеку месяц назад оказывается. вот посмотри описание https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics.

Comment: @paveel163 нужно было добавить только "Iconics.registerFont(new GoogleMaterial());" и всё заработало, спасибо

Comment: Рад что помог)))